# Page authorisation filter - Flutter Web/Firebase Auth

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

Im using FirebaseAuth (email/password) as my authentication to access a page on my Flutter web site. I would like to ensure that the pages/widgets can't be access directly via URL without having a valid user session.

I am currently using the below, which works but it navigates post widget build which seems essential for Navigator to work. However it looks bad from a usability perspective as the page flashes and then returns.

> In initState

```
//Check if user is logged in
    auth.onAuthStateChanged.listen((user) {
      if (user != null) {
        print('User active');
        isLoggedIn = true;
      } else {
        print('User logged out');
        isLoggedIn = false;
      }
    });
```

> In widget build function

```
 if (!isLoggedIn) {
      SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/');
      });
    }
```

The only option I can think of is a "Authorisation" widget that loads on each page first, check the and forwards the user on, but it is still clunky and doesn't really solve my problem well.

> What is a better approach to page security in Flutter web?

Answer (score 0):

Check the package

```
universal_html
```

I think it will work for you. You can use it like this:

> To read & Write

WebStorage.instance.sessionId;

WebStorage.instance.sessionId = 'YOUR_CREDs';

Use it like this

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (Web) {
      isLogin = WebStorage.instance.sessionId != null;
    } else {
      isLogin = //check from local storage;
    }
    return isLogin ? HomePage() : LoginPage();
  }
```

Reference
[Flutter For Web Cookie/Token Sessions and Authentcation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57577071/flutter-for-web-cookie-token-sessions-and-authentcation)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this was what I was trying to avoid if possible.